# C++ Builder procedure entry point CPPdebugHook not found?

Tags: 64-bit, c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

We're trying to build a legacy C++Builder program with the version 11.0 64-bit compiler. We get this error for several DLLs when we run the application:

> The procedure entry point __CPPdebugHook could not be located in the
> dynamic link library <DLL file name>.

We found a mention in the C++Builder docs to add the #pragma link directive (in the main program, we assume), but it didn't seem to help.

Anyone found a solution for this?

Thanks!